# trying to add a formual to the "range" that adjusts which cell will be referenced rather than the value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried making a formula that adjusts which cell will be referenced rather than applying the formula to value of the cell im trying to reference

```
=Q2+11
```

but it just adds 11 to the value of Q2 instead of changing the reference cell to Q2 to Q13

i tried varius combinations of () like

```
=Q(2+11)
```

but it always applied my formula to the referenced cells rather than change the referenced cell to what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler alternative to the previous answer:

```
=offset(Q2,11,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert this formula in the cell where you want to display the results of cell C13:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(+ROW(C2)+11,COLUMN(C2),4))`

It is a combination of several elements:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?sjid=14935560972958955363-AP) - Returns the value of a cell specified by a string.
- [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?sjid=14935560972958955363-AP) - Returns a cell reference as a string.
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?sjid=14935560972958955363-AP) - Returns the row number of a specified cell.
- [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?sjid=14935560972958955363-AP) - Returns the column number of a specified cell

ADDRESS takes the row and column values from cell C2; adds 11 to the Row value to return "C13" as a string

INDIRECT takes the cell reference generated by ADDRESS and displays the value of that cell.

---

[image: snapshot]